# downloading zip files with python mechanize

Tags: python, file, download, zip, mechanize

I am using Python 2.7, mechanize, and beautifulsoup and if it helps I could use urllib

ok, I am trying to download a couple different zip files that are in an different html tables. I know what tables the particular files are in ( I know if they are in the first, second,third ... table)
here is the second table in the html format from the webpage:

```
<table class="fe-form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h2>Eligibility List</h2></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><b>Eligibility File for Met-Ed</b> - 
                <a href="/content/fecorp/supplierservices/eligibility_list.suppliereligibility.html?id=ME&ftype=1&fname=cmb_me_elig_lst_06_2013.zip">cmb_me_elig_lst_06_2013.zip</td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td><b>Eligibility File for Penelec</b> - 
                <a href="/content/fecorp/supplierservices/eligibility_list.suppliereligibility.html?id=PN&ftype=1&fname=cmb_pn_elig_lst_06_2013.zip">cmb_pn_elig_lst_06_2013.zip</td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td><b>Eligibility File for Penn Power</b> - 
                <a href="/content/fecorp/supplierservices/eligibility_list.suppliereligibility.html?id=PP&ftype=1&fname=cmb_pennelig_06_2013.zip">cmb_pennelig_06_2013.zip</td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td><b>Eligibility File for West Penn Power</b> - 
                <a href="/content/fecorp/supplierservices/eligibility_list.suppliereligibility.html?id=WP&ftype=1&fname=cmb_wp_elig_lst_06_2013.zip">cmb_wp_elig_lst_06_2013.zip</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I was going to use the following code just to get to the 2nd table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", class=fe-form)
```

I guess that class="fe-form" is wrong because it will not work, but there are no other attributes of the table that differentiates it from the other tables. All tables have cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50%". I guess I can't use the find() function.

so I am trying to get to the second table and then to download the files on this page. Could someone give me some info to push me in the right direction. I have worked with forms before, but not tables.  I wish there was some way to find the find the particular title of the zip files I am looking for then download them since I will always know their names

Thanks for any help,
Tom

Comment: What about this question. I am trying to download a zip file with python mechanize. The zip file is not in a form it is in a table. Can anyone give my tips to learn how to do this? I have been looking in Google for info on using python mechanize to navigate through tables and can not find anything. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the table you want, simply do

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class' : 'fe-form', 'cellpadding' : '0' })
```

This assumes that there is only one table with class=fe-form and cellpadding=0 in your document. If there are more, this code will select only the first table. To be sure you are not overlooking anything on the page, you could do

```
tables = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class' : 'fe-form', 'cellpadding' : '0' })
table = tables[0]
```

And maybe assert that len(tables)==1 to be sure that there is only one table.

Now, to download the file, there is plenty you can do. Assuming from your code that you have loaded `mechanize`, you could something like

```
a_tags = table.findAll('a')

for a in a_tags:
  if '.zip' in a.get('href'):
    br.retrieve(a.get('href'), a.text)
```

That would download all files to your current working directory and would name them according to their link text.

Comment: I just have not been on this page in a while, thanks for the help djas